# Optimizing over disjoint sets

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization

Given a set $j \in J$, a set $i \in I$, positive coefficients $C_j$, positive values $w_{ij}$.
For each $j$ find set of values of $i$,  $I_j$, such that $\sum_{j \in J} C_j (1- \sum_{i \in I_j}w_{ij})^2$ is minimized subject to the constraints $\sum_{i \in I_j}w_{ij} \le 1$, $\cup_j I_j = I$ and $I_j \cap I_j'= \phi, \forall j,j' \in J$.
Or, find a disjoint partitioning of the set $I$ such that the given function is minimized subject to the less than 1 constraint.

This problem is easily written down in a mixed-integer optimization form. But I am interested in the version of the problem as I wrote. Does this problem have an "easy" solution that is guaranteed optimal? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all constraints in the question itself.  Don't just put clarifications in the comments -- [edit] the question so it is self-contained and people don't need to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

Comment: @D.W. edited to include the union.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-hard, by reduction from the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).  Given integers $x_1,\dots,x_n$ forming an instance of the partition problem, you can set all $w_{ij}$ to $2/(x_1+\dots+x_n)$, set $|J|=2$, $C_j=1$; then any solution to your problem is a solution to the partition problem.  Therefore, there is no "easy" algorithm that is guaranteed to find the optimal solution (unless P=NP).

Comment: Could you be more explicit?